# Multiple select in Material Table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, multiple-select

I want to have a multiple select when editing a row. This is currently what I have

[image: My current table]

I want to change it to multiple select, and whenever I add more items, it gets appended to the Tank column as a string. This is the code for my columns :

```
    const columns = [
    {
        title: "Level",
        field: 'sequence',
        editable: 'onAdd',
    },
    {
        title: 'Tank',
        field: 'tankNo',
    },
    {
        title: "Select ",
        field: 'tankNo',
        lookup: { 'test1': 'select1', 'test2': 'select2' }
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set multiple to true for the Select and use an array to store the value instead of string

Updated usage with material table

```
      {
        title: "Select ",
        field: 'tankNo',
        editComponent: (props) => {
          const { value, onChange } = props;
          return (
           <Select
            labelId="labelId"
            id="selectId"
            multiple={true}
            value={value}
            onChange={(event) => {
              const {
                target: { value }
              } = event;
              onChange(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
            }}
          >
            {["Select 1", "Select 2", "Select 3"].map((option) => (
              <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
                {option}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        );      
     }
    }
```

```
        const [values, setValues] =  useState([])


        handleChange =  event => {
         const {
          target: { value },
         } = event;
         setValues(
         typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value,
         );
        }
       

         <Select
          labelId="labelId"
          id="selectId"
          multiple={true}
          value={values}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
```

Comment: I think that's the problem though. I am using the Material Table from Material UI and I am not sure where to change it to multiple select. It's the one when you edit the table.

Comment: You can use editComponent to override the functionality of the column

Comment: Updated the answer for usage with material-table